# Update calendar from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I would like to update my calendar from a spreadsheet:

I tried the following:

```
function caltest1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var calId = "TestCalendar"; 
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[0];  // First column
    var desc = row[1];       // Second column
    var tstart = row[2];
    var tstop = row[3];
    var loc = row[4];
    //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
    cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc});
 }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "createEvent" of null
```

The following spreadsheet is used:

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OSC6VAxNHFBBVWGt4crjOfbXGSNiwsBYyUg2DkGzgEw/edit?usp=sharing)

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You are passing the calendar's name to `getCalendarById()` so it is returning `null`.  Change "TestCalendar" to the ID of the calendar or use `getCalendarsByName()`.

I will walk you through this the way I read it so you can see one way to  debug this.

This error is telling you that your `cal` variable is `null` on the last line  where you call `cal.createEvent( ... )`.  This means that your earlier statement `var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);` is returning `null`.  Googling the Google Calendar API for this function I see that you are using the correct syntax for `getCalendarId()` but the string argument you are passing appears to be the calendar's name and not the ID.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I changed the function to `getCalendarsByName()`. However, I still get the same error!

Comment: I suggest writing some test code to get the calendar.  Maybe you do this already, but check to make sure you can access your google account, the calendar is shareable as needed, and you have the right name.  Also note, `getCalendarsByName` returns an array and not just one calendar like `getCalendarById` does.  If you get the error 'cannot call method `createEvent` of Array' then you are on the right track.